# Dovecot: setting mail id to start from an arbitrary number

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot

A partner I work with recently switched their mail server host, causing the ids in the old host to "clash" with the ones in the new host, as the id starts from 1 in both hosts.

Is there a configuration that we can set on the new host so that the id can start from some arbitrary number instead, e.g., 1000? This way I can "namespace" the mail ids in the new host to start from some large number that has not been used in the old host.

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you want to combine the two servers ultimately? In that case, you should properly import mails into the new server and let the server deal with ID numbers. I really like `imapsync` to move stuff around IMAP servers ...

Comment: We have an external system that reads these uids, so they must "sync" from outside perspective.